# java date format yyyy-mm-dd.hh.MM.ss.ms

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm receiving a date as a String like this :`2015-07-22.06.05.56.344`. I wrote a parsing code like this

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd.hh.MM.ss.ms");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse("2015-07-22.06.05.56.344");
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I got the output like this:

```
Fri May 22 06:03:44 IST 2015
```

Why is it reading it wrongly? Is it an issue with my code or java cannot recognize this date format?

Comment: Your `mm/MM` are around the wrong way

Comment: Don't know how I missed that!! Silly me :) thanks @MadProgrammer

Comment: Also, there is not format for `ms`, I think you mean `S`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your `MM`/`mm` are around the wrong way, `mm` is for "Minute in hour" and `MM` is for "Month in year"
- `SS` is for "Millisecond" (or `ms`, which means nothing)
- I'd also recommend using `HH` instead of `hh` as `HH` is for "Hour in day (0-23)"

So, using...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.ss.SS");
```

It outputs `Wed Jul 22 06:05:56 EST 2015` for me

Comment: While eveveryone has given the right answer, I'm marking this as the accepted one as maddy was the first to respond.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `MM` for months and `mm` for minutes.

Try setting `SimpleDateFormat` to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.hh.mm.ss.SSS");
```

Check javadoc for more info:
[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: There's nothing called `ms` in SimpleDateFormat. It will be treated as month and second instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong pattern. The pattern is case sensitive.

mm stands for minutes
MM stand for month.

SS is  miliseconds

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.hh.mm.ss.SSS");
```

For more details see [the SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)