# selecting files with regex

Tags: java, regex, datetime

I'm doing a project at college where my method is using a regex to pull the date out of the name of each of the log files in a folder, and then, after comparing the millisec stamp with one defined by the Ndays parameter passed in, delete it if its older than the required date (eg; 30 days ago- params passed in will be 30 and the file that contains the logs)....

Much appreciate any assistance.....my below attempt isn't working.....

```
public void deleteFilesOlderThanNdays( int Ndays, String aFolder) throws
        ParseException{ 
    File directory = new File(aFolder);
    if(directory.exists()){ 

        File[] logFiles = directory.listFiles();

        for (File log: logFiles) {
            String name= log.getName();
            //Pattern dateFind = Pattern.compile("\\d\\{0,10}");// or
            Pattern dateFind = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
            Matcher dateSearch =dateFind.matcher(name);

            while(dateSearch.find()){
                String logDate = dateSearch.toString();
                SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.mm.dd");
                Date date= format.parse(logDate);
                long cutOffPoint = System.currentTimeMillis() - (Ndays* 24*60*60*1000);
                if(date.getTime()< cutOffPoint){
                    log.delete();
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java date format yyyy-mm-dd.hh.MM.ss.ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870275/java-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss-ms)

Comment: What do you mean not working? What's it doing that it shouldn't be? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: You're calling `toString()` on a `Matcher`. The format of this is unspecified.

Comment: You're using lowercase `m` instead of uppercase `M` (check [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details). And you're using `.` in the formatter, but the pattern extracted from the file name seems to have `-`. And you should call `dateSearch.group()` instead of `dateSearch.toString()`

Comment: Why are you even doing this in a nested loop? You want to delete the files that have expired, right? then why the nesting? It can cause a problem if you try to delete a file that has already been deleted.

Comment: And *isn't working* is too vague. You should **[edit]** the question and include at least the error message (no need to put the whole stacktrace). Some examples would also be fine (e.g. some files names and expected results vs what you're getting). Please take a look at [ask] and how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry guys,and thanks for that suggestion DD, and thanks Hugo and bcsb, it now works like a dream....feel like a schoolboy but on one hand it makes a nice change to have no major fundamental problem as usual...thanks folks......its working aok now.......

Comment: Would you add an answer below, in an answer post, to show how you fixed it?

Comment: It turned out to be the simple mistakes pointed out by the replies above, the mm in the date format instead of the MM, and calling the group() method in place of toString() method on the Matcher object...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the simple mistakes pointed out by the replies above, the mm in the date format instead of the MM, and calling the group() method in place of toString() method on the Matcher object..regards guys....